# Reshaping dataframe in R for twin data

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame like the one shown below. Each pair of ID numbers (e.g. 2891, 2892) corresponds to pair of twins.

```
    ID zyg.x CDsum
1 2891     2     0            
2 2892     2     5            
3 4000     1     0           
4 4001     1     0            
5 4006     2     0
6 4007     2     3
```

I would like to reshape this data frame to make it look like this... Note that the zyg.x (zygosity) value is the same for each twin in the pair.

```
           Twin Pair     zyg   CDsumTwin1   CDsumTwin2
1   pair1(2891,2892)       2            0            5
2   pair2(4000,4001)       1            0            0
3   pair3(4006,4007)       2            0            3
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Data:

```
df <- read.table(text = "    ID zyg.x CDsum
1 2891     2     0            
2 2892     2     5            
3 4000     1     0           
4 4001     1     0            
5 4006     2     0
6 4007     2     3")
```

Arrange by ID and create a variable "twin" to distinguish the two twins in each pair

```
df<- df %>%
  arrange(ID) %>%
  mutate(twin = rep(c(1, 2),length.out = n()))

df
    ID zyg.x CDsum twin
1 2891     2     0    1
2 2892     2     5    2
3 4000     1     0    1
4 4001     1     0    2
5 4006     2     0    1
6 4007     2     3    2
```

Split df into two dataframes - for twin1 and twin2

```
twin1 <- df %>%
  filter(twin == 1) %>%
  select(-twin) %>%
  rename(CDsumTwin1 = CDsum, 
         ID1 = ID)

twin1
   ID1 zyg.x CDsumTwin1
1 2891     2          0
3 4000     1          0
5 4006     2          0

twin2 <- df %>%
  filter(twin == 2) %>%
  select(-twin) %>%
  rename(CDsumTwin2 = CDsum,
         ID2 = ID)

twin2
   ID2 zyg.x CDsumTwin2
2 2892     2          5
4 4001     1          0
6 4007     2          3
```

cbind, combine and rearrange columns:

```
twin1 %>% cbind(twin2 %>% select(-zyg.x)) %>%
  mutate(`Twin Pair` = paste0("pair (", ID1, ", ", ID2, ")")) %>%
  select(`Twin Pair`, zyg.x, CDsumTwin1, CDsumTwin2)
    
          Twin Pair zyg.x CDsumTwin1 CDsumTwin2
1 pair (2891, 2892)     2          0          5
3 pair (4000, 4001)     1          0          0
5 pair (4006, 4007)     2          0          3
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply.

When running your last piece of code, I get this: Error: Can't transform a data frame with duplicate names. How can I get around this? Thanks again.

Comment: @ericm, the code runs well, are you copying it correctly? There should not be duplicate names, as I am dropping `zyg.x` from twin2 dataframe when doing a `cbind`

Answer (score 0):

Here is how we could achieve this with `dplyr` only:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  mutate(rn = ceiling(row_number()/2)) %>% 
  group_by(rn) %>% 
  mutate(Twin_Pair = paste0(ID, collapse = ","),
         Twin_Pair = paste0("pair",rn, "(",Twin_Pair, ")")) %>% 
  mutate(CDsumTwin1 = first(CDsum),
         CDsumTwin2 = last(CDsum), .keep="unused") %>%  
  slice(2) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  select(Twin_Pair, zyg=zyg.x, CDsumTwin1, CDsumTwin2)
```

output:

```
  Twin_Pair          zyg CDsumTwin1 CDsumTwin2
  <chr>            <dbl>      <dbl>      <dbl>
1 pair1(2891,2892)     2          0          5
2 pair2(4000,4001)     1          0          0
3 pair3(4006,4007)     2          0          3
```